# UIWebView not loading mobile site

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, web, uiwebview

I know this was covered before, but none of the methods mentioned worked for me,

I need UIWebView to load a mobile website, but instead it returns desktop version

I tried

```
NSMutableURLRequest *stadiumURLRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/"]];
[stadiumURLRequest setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[stadiumWebView loadRequest:stadiumURLRequest];
```

and in the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

NSMutableDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"mobileApp" forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"1" forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"www.example.com" forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"www.example.com" forKey:NSHTTPCookieOriginURL];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"/" forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"0" forKey:NSHTTPCookieVersion];

NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any of that. Just create stadiumURLRequest and then call loadRequest:. The problem stems from the server itself which doesn't seem to return the mobile version. Does it work on safari on a device?

Comment: Thanks, told that to website administrators and they fixed the issue by changing metadata

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to add the headers, they are sent by default, also, see if it loads in safari and its not just the websites problem

Comment: Any suggestions on a site that loads the proper mobile version through Safari in the simulator, but does not load correctly in my fullscreen UIWebView?